# Manage both args and kwargs in a python inheritance hierarchy

Tags: python, function, inheritance, arguments

Are there any "good" way to manage both args and kwargs in a inheritance hierarchy like I tried in this code. I mean without to get a value with a specified key in kwargs or something like this...

It is supposed to display `1 2 3 4` :

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, motherArg1, motherArg2=100):
        self.motherArg1 = motherArg1
        self.motherArg2 = motherArg2
    def printParent(self):
        print self.motherArg1
        print self.motherArg2

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, childArg1, *args, childArg2=100, **kwargs): # Doesn't work here
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.childArg1 = childArg1
        self.childArg2 = childArg2
    def printChild(self):
        print self.childArg1
        print self.childArg2

child = Child(1, 3, childArg2=2, motherArg2=4)
child.printChild()
child.printParent()
```

The syntax is not good : expected ");" after *args.

And `def __init__(self, childArg1, childArg2=100, *args, **kwargs)` is a right syntax but doesn't work.

1. When I try this syntax and `child = Child(1, childArg2=2, 3, motherArg2=4)`, I get **SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg**
2. And when I try `child = Child(1, 3, childArg2=2, motherArg2=4)` I get **TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'childArg2'**

Comment: Please [edit] to include that, properly formatted, *in the question itself*. In this case it's pretty obvious what output you would get but a [mcve] is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you rename `printChild` of the parent to `printParent` (and fix the `print`s) it already works in python 3, as suggested:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But you can get it to work for python2, too. You'd do this by removing entries in `kwargs` which are supposed to be relevant for the child before you pass them on to the parent.

Code (working for python3):

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, motherArg1, motherArg2=100):
        self.motherArg1 = motherArg1
        self.motherArg2 = motherArg2
    def printParent(self):
        print(self.motherArg1)
        print(self.motherArg2)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, childArg1, *args, childArg2=100, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.childArg1 = childArg1
        self.childArg2 = childArg2
    def printChild(self):
        print(self.childArg1)
        print(self.childArg2)

child = Child(1, 3, childArg2=2, motherArg2=4)
child.printChild()
child.printParent()
```

Code for python2

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, motherArg1, motherArg2=100):
        self.motherArg1 = motherArg1
        self.motherArg2 = motherArg2
    def printParent(self):
        print(self.motherArg1)
        print(self.motherArg2)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, childArg1, *args, **kwargs): 
        # this shows the concept, it can be formulated more elegantly
        # with @Martijn Pieters answer's 'pop':
        if 'childArg2' in kwargs:
            childArg2 = kwargs['childArg2']
            del kwargs['childArg2']
        else:
            childArg2 = 2
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.childArg1 = childArg1
        self.childArg2 = childArg2
    def printChild(self):
        print(self.childArg1)
        print(self.childArg2)

child = Child(1, 3, childArg2=2, motherArg2=4)
child.printChild()
child.printParent()
```

Comment: Since the OP is using explicit `object` and the `print` statement, not to mention is reporting that their code *doesn't* work, it's pretty clear that they are using 2.x. Telling them it works in 3.x isn't terribly useful.

Comment: you're right. I've now added a python 2 version

Comment: No you said it works on Python 3, so maybe I prefer change my python version. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, you must put the `*args` argument **after** any explicit keyword arguments:

```
def __init__(self, childArg1, childArg2=100, *args, **kwargs):
```

However, you can't then use additional positional parameters *anyway* as they are captured by the `childArg2` argument:

```
>>> child = Child(1, 3, childArg2=2, motherArg2=4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'childArg2'
```

Your only option is to take keyword arguments from the `**kwargs` dictionary:

```
def __init__(self, childArg1, *args, **kwargs):
    childArg2 = kwargs.pop('childArg2', 2)
```

This makes `childArg2` work only as an explicit keyword argument, and `*args` captures all additional positional arguments:

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...     def __init__(self, motherArg1, motherArg2=100):
...         self.motherArg1 = motherArg1
...         self.motherArg2 = motherArg2
...     def printParent(self):
...         print self.motherArg1
...         print self.motherArg2
...
>>> class Child(Parent):
...     def __init__(self, childArg1, *args, **kwargs):
...         childArg2 = kwargs.pop('childArg2', 2)
...         super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...         self.childArg1 = childArg1
...         self.childArg2 = childArg2
...     def printChild(self):
...         print self.childArg1
...         print self.childArg2
...
>>> child = Child(1, 3, childArg2=2, motherArg2=4)
>>> child.printChild()
1
2
>>> child.printParent()
3
4
```